# What mean of the green N of the table in DbWrench

Tags: database-design

I am use DbWrench to design my table, but I don't know what mean of the GreenN mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That means nullable, that is to say the `bookstore_Id`'s value in your table can be `null`.

From the official video, you can learn it:

http://www.dbwrench.com/videos/video_base.shtml